# creating a hardlink to a file contained in one subdirectory into another subdirectory

Tags: shell, unix, hardlink

hey guys so im using Ubuntu and im having a issue finding the files using the ln command

currently i have a folder called myName.2 within it are 3 folders notes, assignments and web.
within notes i created 3 files called linux.txt, unix.txt and shell.txt, now i have redirected myself so im in the folder web and want to create hard links to these files here, so for example i type the command

```
ln /home/admin/3000/Assignment1/myName.2/notes/linux.txt
```

however the terminal is telling me,

```
ln: accessing `/home/admin/3000/Assignment1/myName.2/notes/linux.txt': No such file or directory
```

i went to the properties of the linux text file and copy and pasted the path straight from there

any hints would be much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to make typos, and simpler to use relative paths.  Try:

```
ln ../notes/linux.txt
```

from inside the `web` directory.